# List changed files and folders compared to disk image

Tags: hard-disk, disk-image, data

Let's call the image *Disk.img*, taken from /dev/sda.

How do I list every file and folder with differences?

(Let's assume the time stamps of the files are incorrect.)

Answer (score 1):

I usually mount the disk image somewhere and `find` all the files from it's "root" directory (the root of the mount point) issuing an `sha1sum` against every file it finds.

Then, change to the root directory of the FS you want to check and run `sha1sum` against the list of saved sums (you need to issue `find` from the roots so the paths to the files are the same in the `sha1sum` output)

It's a little greasy because missing files will cause errors and filenames with spaces or shell meta-charcters will give you trouble as well but it's about the best way I've found of finding duplicate files or detecting changes.

- mount the image somewhere (`mount -o ro /root/Disk.img /mnt/disk_img`)
- `cd /mnt/disk_img && find . -type f -exec sha1sum '{}' \; > tmp/disk_img.sums`
- `umount /mnt/disk_img`
- `cd / && sha1sum -c /tmp/disk_img.sums`